# call parent method in child component using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, methods, components, parent-child, parent

hello everyone i jusy wanna know how to call a perent function from a child component
i've tried to use the $parent to call the perent method but i have this error typeError: _this.$parent.forceRender is not a function
here's the parent method that i'm trying to call

```
methods: {
      forceRender() {
        this.componentKey += 1
      }
    },
```

and here's the child component as you can see i'm trying to call the parent method using the $parent

```
this.$parent.forceRender()
```

Comment: By the way: `forceRerender` sounds like it's a bad idea. You usually should not have to do something like that.

Answer (score 12):

You can send the functions as a props to the child component jus like follows

```
<child-component :forceRender="forceRender" />
```

inside the child component you can received it like this

```
props: ['forceRender']
```

and then call it as

```
this.forceRender()
```

Answer (score 4):

You should emit an event from child to parent component in order to run a parent method :

in child component:

```
this.$emit('force-render')
```

in parent component add `@force-render` to component tag with `forceRender` as handler :

```
<child-component @force-render="forceRender" />
```